# firefox plugin - How to hide a tab browser and getting its content

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul, tabbed-browsing

I am developing a plugin for firefox. In which i have to open a hidden tab and access its content through javascript and close it afterwards.

Following is the code i am using for accessing content of a tab:

```
var newTabBrowser = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(gBrowser.addTab("www.kayak.com/flights#/BOM-ORL/2013-05-14/2013-06-19"));
var contentdata = "";
newTabBrowser.addEventListener("load", function () {
    contentdata = contentdata + newTabBrowser.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
    load = load + 1;
    if(load == 5) {
        var DOMPars = new DOMParser();
        var dom = DOMPars.parseFromString(contentdata, "text/html");
        var priceNode = dom.getElementById('low_price');
    }
}, true);
```

How can i hide this tab in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like you just need to create a permanent, invisible page and access its DOM.

Addon-SDK provide a [page-work](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/page-worker.html) module. Do this what you want?

Comment: This is interesting. I wasn't aware of it, actually it does what i really want to implement. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

If you store a reference to the tab you open with addTab, you can hide that tab using css or other available methods.
For example:

```
var newTab = gBrowser.addTab("www.kayak.com/flights#/BOM-ORL/2013-05-14/2013-06-19");
newTab.setAttribute("style", "display: none");

var newTabBrowser = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(newTab);
newTabBrowser.loadCount = 0;
var contentdata = "";
newTabBrowser.addEventListener("load", function () {
    contentdata = contentdata + newTabBrowser.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
    this.loadCount = this.loadCount + 1;
    if(this.loadCount == 5) {
        var DOMPars = new DOMParser();
        var dom = DOMPars.parseFromString(contentdata, "text/html");
        var priceNode = dom.getElementById('low_price');
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: I tried this earlier but do not get content when set attribute display to none. I was able to access innerHTML only when it is visible. Is there any other way to hide and get the content?

Comment: Updated the example, you had a **local** variable "load" so it never became 5.

Comment: Actually a catch here is- that particular url gets completely loaded only after calling callback function 5 times hence i put if condition because otherwise i won't get the correct data. It is somehow working now. Thanks @martijn appreciate it.